# solving the eight queens to produce a solution

Tags: java, n-queens

Below is my attempt at solving the 8 queens problem to print one solution. (place 8 queens on a chessboard such that none of them are attacking each other). However, this solution only places 6 queens. I need another opinion of where I am making a mistake. I'm doing this in more of a BFS style instead of backtracking.

Comment: please, format your code properly

Comment: Cheers Casey, not really used to formatting on this website.

Comment: It's hard to tell where your problem is if you don't even know. Please try and focus your question on a specific problem.

Comment: I'm only getting an output of 6 queens (six 1s). I'm getting only 0s on rows 5 and 6

Comment: please explain the logic behind your code

Comment: I'm trying to implement the BFS method.

Comment: In the print if solution, if you output the coordinates, it repeats 1,6 and 2,4 twice for "found coordinates." There appears to be a logic issue of some sort in the recursion that results in the same place being set to 0 and rechecked.

Comment: Hmm thanks I understand the problem however solving this will be tough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your algorithm is malfunctioning at some point. Upon running it, I found the following issues:

1. You are constantly setting `visited[i][j]` to 0 in your for loop in main. This always resets visited to 0 even if a recursion call is made. In fact, when you declare both `visited` and `board` they are initiated to arrays full of 0s. So you can get rid of both set statements in there. In addition, because you reset the arrays, your recursive function ends up setting both values to 0 and then finds them again."
2. For debugging, in the `!hasQueen` statement, you should output the `board[row][col]` coordinates, which show you the coordinates that have been found. The final list before it prints out the grid shows that 2,4 and 1,6 are found and set twice.
3. The actual chessboard that is output ends up with an impossible solution:

> 1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
>
> 0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0
>
> 0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0
>
> 0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0
>
> 0  0  0  X  0  Y  0  0
>
> 0  0  0  Y  0  X  0  0
>
> 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1
>
> 0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0

(sorry I can't get the numbers to format)

Both layout X and layout Y fail the 8 queens rules.

If you run your program with the setting to 0 commented out, you will see that it grinds to a halt after finding 6 locations.

Comment: Have you considered reading the wiki entry? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_queens_puzzle It appears your 4th line-finding is what invalidates it with a top-left queen solution.